# Filtering values based on column values to others

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
newd = {'year': [2001, 2002, 2005, 2002, 2004, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2004, 2004 ],
 'indviduals': [12, 23, 24, 28,30, 15, 17, 18, 18, 19, 12, 15, 12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 15, 12, 12],
 'employers': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'] }


newdf=newdf=pd.DataFrame(newd)
```

My expected outcome (just an example):

```
2001, a: [12, 15, 17] count:3  employerchanged: []
2002, b: [12, 23, 28] count:3  employerchanged: [12] 
2002, a: [15]         count:1
```

This when done in SQL is easy. But SQL won't tell me a way if individual '12' changed employer between year 2001 and 2002.

This is what I have tried so far in python:

```
dic={}

listofUniqueYears= [i for i in newdf.year.unique()]
```

# gives me list of unique years

```
dic={}

for i in listofUniqueYears:
   dic[i]=defaultdict(dict)

    print(dic)
```

My question is how do I filter row values based on condition I supply, in this scenario, I want to have number of employees, count and changed employee per year per employer.

Comment: Does each individual only have a single entry (row) per year?

Comment: yes, but they might have two employer  for that year

Comment: example print(newdf[newdf['year']==2004]). individual 12 has two employers in 2004

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a group-by to get the unique count of employers per employee per year.

```
df = newdf.groupby(['year','indviduals']).agg({'employers':'nunique'}).reset_index()
df[df.year == 2004]
```

You can also apply further aggregations if you need the sum of counts depending on what you require.